# SQL Syntax errors with multiple joins

Tags: sql, mariadb, syntax-error, inner-join

I was writing a client in C to manage a library information system. I wrote this sql query in the client, but I have this syntax error.  Can someone help me to find this error? thanks.

> ERROR --> Error 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;
> check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for
> the right syntax to use near 'as CD inner join COPIA as C on
> (CD.COPIA_idCOPIA = C.idCOPIA) inner join LIBRO a' at line 1

CODE:

```
  snprintf(q, 1024, "SELECT CD.COPIA_idCOPIA, CD.Ripiano, CD.Scaffale 
                     FROM COPIA DISPONIBILE as CD 
                            inner join COPIA as C on (CD.COPIA_idCOPIA = C.idCOPIA) 
                            inner join LIBRO as L on (C.LIBRO_idLIBRO = L.idLIBRO) 
                            inner join POSSEDERE as P on (C.idCOPIA = P.COPIA_idCOPIA) 
            WHERE P.BIBLIOTECA_idBIBLIOTECA = '%d' and L.Nome = '%s'", idBiblioteca, buffer);
        
  if(mysql_query(conn, q)!= 0) {
       print_error (conn, "query SELECT statement failed");
  } else {
       printf ("query SELECT statement succeeded: %lu rows affected(unsignedlong)mysql_affected_rows   (conn));
  }
```

Comment: Please tag the correct DB, I think you are using Maria DB and not mysql.

Comment: remove `DISPONIBILE`! must be `FROM COPIA as CD`

Comment: there is a table COPIA and a table COPIA DISPONIBILE

Comment: Normally in SQL `%` is a wildcard character. When using wildcards, you have to use `LIKE` not `=`

Comment: Jonathan Willcock -- LIKE seems don't work. Same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your table is really called `COPIA DISPONIBILE` with a space in it, you'll have to escape it by surrounding it with backticks:

```
snprintf(q, 1024, "SELECT CD.COPIA_idCOPIA, CD.Ripiano, CD.Scaffale 
                     FROM `COPIA DISPONIBILE` as CD 
                            inner join COPIA as C on (CD.COPIA_idCOPIA = C.idCOPIA) 
                            inner join LIBRO as L on (C.LIBRO_idLIBRO = L.idLIBRO) 
                            inner join POSSEDERE as P on (C.idCOPIA = P.COPIA_idCOPIA) 
            WHERE P.BIBLIOTECA_idBIBLIOTECA = '%d' and L.Nome = '%s'", idBiblioteca, buffer);
```

Comment: Escaping with backticks is ok too: `FROM \`COPIA DISPONIBILE\` as CD`

Comment: Mureinik -- also escaping seems don't work.. Same error

Comment: @juergen d -- with the backstick seems to work.. and the if statements print : " query SELECT statement succeeded........"

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice this was [tag:mysql]. Escaping a table name should indeed use backticks. Edited and fixed.